# How can I edit my fstab file?

Tags: fstab, cd-drive

Unfortunately, I cannot use my Cdrom. Could someone help me?

```
/etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0r/180
```

```
loop6                   7:6    0   3,3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/36
loop7                   7:7    0   1,8M  1 loop /snap/quadrapassel/44
loop8                   7:8    0  86,9M  1 loop /snap/core/4917
loop9                   7:9    0   3,7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
loop10                  7:10   0  12,2M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/69
loop11                  7:11   0   140M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/59
loop12                  7:12   0  34,7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
loop13                  7:13   0   1,6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/154
loop14                  7:14   0    21M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/25
loop15                  7:15   0 140,9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
sda                     8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk 
└─sda1                  8:1    0 465,8G  0 part 
  ├─ubuntu--vg-root   253:0    0 464,8G  0 lvm  /
  └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 253:1    0   976M  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sr0                    11:0    1     2K  0 rom
```

Comment: Why do you think you need something in `fstab` for your cdrom to work? What is the output of `lsblk` ? What happens if you insert a CD?

Comment: The `lsblk` output is not quite right. Please make sure you've copied it correctly, then select it all and press the code formatting button `{}` to format it properly.

Comment: You don't need to insert anything int your `fstab` to use CD/DVDs.  `sr0` is your CD/DVD drive, you simply need to insert a disk, then manually mount it somewhere and then use the data.  If you try and put it into `/etc/fstab` and you don't have a disc in it (and you don't set `noauto` to not permit it to automount at boot) it will fail to boot properly (and/or take an eon to boot)